# how to pass environment variable for target redis hosts in redisinsight k8s deployment yaml

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redisinsights

recently i'm working on deploying redisinsight to my AWS EKS cluster, I don't want to manage/add any of my infra component manually, so I'm trying to pass my redis hosts as environment variables to k8s deployment yaml. But as far as I understood, it is not being supported.

Is there a configuration something like REDIS_HOSTS ;

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redisinsight
  namespace : xxx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 40%
      maxUnavailable: 10%
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redisinsight
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        owner: xxx
        app: redisinsight
    spec:
      containers:
      - name:  redisinsight
        image: redislabs/redisinsight:1.7.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        volumeMounts:
        - name: db
          mountPath: /db
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8001
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 500Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 100Mi
        env:
        - name: RIHOST
          value: xxx.yyy.zzz
        - name: REDIS_HOSTS
          value: redishost1.example.com:6379,redishost2.example.com:6379
      volumes:
      - name: db
        emptyDir: {}
```

Is it possible?
Thank you.